# FabricJS - how to show separate rotation handle?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I have started using FabricJS, and I see in all the demos that the rotation handle is above the object and separated from the resize.

But in my page, this rotation handle is not visible and I can rotate only using the resize handles. I have tried adding: `hasRotatingPoint: true` but it doesn't do anything. I am using FabricJS 0.9.15.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're using 0.9.15...The "hasRotatingPoint" property exists in version 1.0+ so you might want to upgrade :)

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tree/master/dist